# cover up text in powerpoint using random clicking

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've made a jeopardy like game for my students and I want to cover up each category as they answer it. I've created the box that covers the category, but I cannot figure out how to allow each section to appear without it appearing in the order I created the boxes. These need to be random. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Maybe you need to use macro to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using animation to do this? If so, you can use trigger function in animations. You can use the questions as trigger points so that the boxes appear when you click on the questions. I'm not sure if that's what you mean but hope this helps